# regex to match a string but not within a pattern

Tags: json, regex, pattern-matching

I have the following JSON and am looking to find the id value (1234 in this example) outside of the files JSON Array. What would the regex be in this case?

```
{ 
  "id":"abc1234",
  "name":"test",
  "files":[
    { 
      "id":"abc1",
      "name":"test1"
    },
    { 
      "id":"abc2",
      "name":"test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the JSON fields are not in a guaranteed order, so the outer id field could come after the files JSON array.

The following captures the first instance of it, but I need to somehow negate matches within the files JSON array.

```
\b(?:id":")(\w+)\b
```

Comment: This is probably not a problem you want to solve with regular expressions, but by parsing the JSON using functionality in whatever language you are writing in.

Comment: I am with Andy lester. Getting the JSON array into an Array of Bean object is much better idea. and most appropriate way.

Comment: This maybe a bit "greedy" but works with EditPad, for example.  `"+(\d)+"`

Comment: So don't have a programming language to work with here. Also the ids in the files array can be numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

I **would not use a regex** to solve your problem but a JSON parser.

However, if you want to use regex you can use something like this:

```
id":"(\d+).*files|files.*id":"(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP7nR7/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that regex is not good choice in parsing the JSON, and it was many times explained on SO why it is not good idea, but in the end it is up to you what you will use, so if for some mysterious reason you decide to go with regex, you can try with:

```
(\s*)\{\s\n(?=(\s+))[\s\S]*?^\2"id":"(?<ID>\d+)"[\s\S]*?^\1\}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wZ9pN9/2)

it match whole part, but you will get desired value in ID group.